# How to make this code works as asynchronous program

Tags: c++, winapi, c++98

Today I'd implement a very basic Thread class. My question is why this code run synchronously:

```
struct Clerk : public Thread
{
    Clerk()
    {
        IsOnService = false;
    }
    void Run()
    {
        std::deque<int> dq;
        std::cout << this->GetId() << " receive new customer " << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) dq.push_front(i);
        std::cout << this->GetId() << " has finished" << '\n';

        IsOnService = false;
    }

    bool IsOnService;
};

struct Customer
{
    bool IsOnService;
};

struct Service
{
    Clerk*      clerk;
    Customer*   customer;
    Service(Clerk* c, Customer* cu)
    {
        clerk = c;
        customer = cu;
        clerk->Join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    int nClerks = 5;
    Clerk* clerks[] = { 
        new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk()
    };

    while (1) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x43) & 0x7FFF) {
            Customer* newCustomer = new Customer();
            for (int i = 0; i < nClerks; ++i)
                if (!clerks[i]->IsOnService) {
                    Service* newService = new Service(clerks[i], newCustomer);
                    delete newService;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nClerks; ++i) delete clerks[i];
    return 0;
}
```

## First

The deque is only for make a hard work that takes several time, but when I run the code above it takes time but run thread per thread I mean I have something like this when I run it:

`C:>100 receive new customer`

... several time ...

`C:>100 has finished`

`C:>150 receive new customer`

... several time ...

`C:>150 has finished`

... and so on

And the behavior that I wish to have is the following:

`C:>100 receive new customer`

`C:>150 receive new customer`

`C:>100 has finished`

`C:>150 has finished`

Or something like that. If someone can help me. I'd used deque because I want to make a task that takes time but the code needs to compile in C++98. Plz don't answer me with code that is implemented in C++11 or higher.

Comment: Unrelated: C++03 never gets any respect.

Comment: Unrelated: Save some dynamic allocation and replace `Clerk* clerks[] = { new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk()};` with `Clerk clerks[5];`and `Service* newService = new Service(clerks[i], newCustomer); delete newService;` with `Service newService(&clerks[i], newCustomer);` Remember C++ isn't some barbaric language where you have to `new` everything.

Comment: It's rather difficult to figure out why code runs synchronously without seeing the code that is supposed to make things run in parallel. You should give a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. In particular, what does your custom `Thread` class look like? What is the `Join` function that is being called?

Comment: @JaMiT I have the advantage having commented on this exact bug when the asker asked about the [Thread class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018730/how-to-deal-with-multiple-parameters-of-different-types-in-c98) a few hours earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you add a job to a `Clerk` with

```
Service(Clerk* c, Customer* cu)
{
    clerk = c;
    customer = cu;
    clerk->Join();
}
```

Lifting the `Join` function from the Asker's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018730/how-to-deal-with-multiple-parameters-of-different-types-in-c98)

```
void Thread::Join()
{
    m_handle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &this->call, 0, 0, 0);
    if (m_handle) WaitForSingleObject(m_handle, INFINITE);
}
```

we can see that the calling thread stops dead and waits for the `Clerk`'s thread to complete. In other words, main thread stops, `Clerk` thread runs to completion and then main thread resumes and queues the next job to the next `Clerk`. No two `Clerk`s are ever active at the same time.

You need to add jobs to the `Clerk`s and let the `Clerk`s run with one, and only one, thread per `Clerk`. When there are no more jobs to be added, then you join on the `Clerk`s. This requires a fairly big re-write of the `Thread` class from the previous question.

What you really want here is to make yourself a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) of `Clerk`s.

Rethink `Service`, by the way. There's no need for a class here. Since Service is created, is destroyed immediately after, and doesn't really need to maintain any state while it is alive, a [free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861914/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-free-function-in-c) will be sufficient.

Comment: We don't actually know what Join does.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give me a basic example? Thx

Comment: Maybe you can search some examples in github or codeproject.